# Error creating android subproject when using phonegap run android command

Tags: android, command-line-interface

I installed nodejs and did the following:

```
npm install -g phonegap
phonegap create <app path>
cd <app path>
phonegap run android
```

when i execute the run android command, I get below error:

```
An error occurred during creation of android-sub project.  The system cannot find the project specified.
```

not sure where this is coming from.

any clues.

Thanks

Comment: Any chance you have whitespaces? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17846818/1135469

Comment: Whitespace was a problem in my case of the same error!

Comment: did you get any solution other then whitespace as I am getting same error.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problems and a hard time finding a solution, however:

1. Make sure JAVA is installed

   - Set JAVA_HOME & PATH variables
2. Make sure ANT is installed

   - Set ANT_HOME & PATH variables
3. Make sure Android SDK is installed

   - Add PATH to sdk/tools
   - Add PATH to sdk/platform-tool
   - Run SDK manager to update & install SDK elements
   - Run AVD manager to create a default emulator image
4. Install NodeJS (with PATH)

   - Follow the usual tutorials
   - npm install -g cordova

     - cordova create hello com.sample.hello HelloWorld
     - cd hello
     - cordova platform add android
     - cordova build
     - now launch your Emulator
     - cordova emulate android (patience, take ages...)
     - or
     - cordova run android

       - much faster, just make sure you mobile device is connected, on, unlocked, usb debug is on, and drivers are installed
       - if you can't find one try: sdk\extras\google\usb_driver
   - npm install -g phonegap

     - phonegap create hello com.sample.hello HelloWorld
     - cd hello
     - phonegap platform add android (if not working use cordova command)
     - phonegap build android
     - now your launch Emulator
     - phonegap emulate android (patience, take ages...)
     - or
     - phonegap run android

       - much faster, just make sure you mobile device is connected, on, unlocked, usb debug is on, and drivers are installed
       - if you can't find one try: sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

I think the main difference between phonegap/cordova, is phonegap (which belong to Adobe) has the possibility to build in the cloud via https://build.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace is not allowed i would say