# PhoneGap Unable to Build IOS using Phonegap 3.0.0

Tags: ios, cordova

Based on the tutorial 'http://phonegap.com/install/'

I have installed  "sudo npm install -g phonegap"

Then have created "phonegap create my-app"

Then Went inside the created app "cd my-app"

Then ran "phonegap local build ios"

but its throwing an error ---

"An error occured during creation of ios sub-project. /bin/sh: /Users/IOS2/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.0.0/bin/create: No such file or directory"

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773075/cordova-cli-an-error-occurred-during-creation-of-ios-sub-project

Comment: I found the answer, just downloaded the Binary from github and then added in to user/myname/cordova/lib/ios-> mydownloaded binary in my case 3.0.0-> bin, and once i used phonegap cli, phonegap local build ios, it worked!!