# Why is my cordova bin folder missing?

Tags: cordova

So I installed PhoneGap 3.0.0:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Then I created a project:

```
phonegap create Test com.example.test Test
```

This created the folder with the following folders:

- merges (empty)
- platforms (empty)
- plugins (empty)
- www (contains default web assets)

Then I built the project for iOS:

```
phonegap build ios
```

And I got the following error:

```
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the iOS platform...
[error] An error occured during creation of ios sub-project. /bin/sh: /Users/dbank/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.0.0/bin/create: No such file or directory
```

Sure enough, when I went to this folder (.../cordova/3.0.0), there was no bin folder.

When I just type the 'phonegap' command, I see the following:

```
keyword | local environment | remote environment
------------------------------------------------
ios     | Yes               | Yes
```

Please can anyone tell me why I do not have this bin folder when I installed phonegap?

Comment: Looks like you need to rm -rf your ~/.cordova folder.

[Previous Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773075/cordova-cli-an-error-occurred-during-creation-of-ios-sub-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who gets stuck on this issue, 10gistic's comment is correct.  I needed to remove the .cordova folder in my root directory.  After I did that I was able build the iOS sub-project successfully.

See the following StackOverflow question: [Cordova CLI: an error occurred during creation of ios sub-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773075/cordova-cli-an-error-occurred-during-creation-of-ios-sub-project)