# Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project

Tags: android, windows, cordova

I was try to use the [tutorial](http://www.techariv.in/2013/08/creating-android-hello-cordova.html) to create android app.
But after using the command

```
cordova -d create Hellos com.example.hello "Hellos"
```

to create project.After that i executed the command

```
cordova platform add android
```

to add android platform.but i got error

```
[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. The system cann
ot find the path specified.]
```

i tried soln in

[An error occurred during creation of android sub-project because a path is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159253/an-error-occurred-during-creation-of-android-sub-project-because-a-path-is-not-f)

[Error creating android subproject when using phonegap run android command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555135/error-creating-android-subproject-when-using-phonegap-run-android-command)

but after using those solns also i couldn't get rid of error.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry guys,I have deleted .cordova file inside project instead of deleting the one in root folder.After deleting that it was working fine.

Comment: please tell me which .coredova file is needed to delete

Comment: `.cordova` directory under C:\Users\user_name\

Comment: i deleted that still the same issue bro

Comment: sorry bro, i dont have more knowledge about that,you could post a new question if the solns linked in question didnt solve your problem.

Comment: actually i found the issue now . its adt installation . Adt is sucking with XP

Comment: Then please post your solution here ,which might help others in future

Comment: I uninstalled xp and installed window 7 and working now in window 7

Answer (score 1):

At first make sure that the `android-tools` and `platform-tools` are in your path environment, then delete the `.cordova` from your home directory and repeat again.